# Is there a possibilty to activate front camera flash on Samsung phones?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, flashlight

Im currently trying to activate the built in front flashlight on a Samsung Galaxy A6, but the device provides information like there is no built in front flash.

I've already tried different methods, which can be found by searching for activating flash.

1. First Try was to get supportedFlashModes and then activate the flash by using setParameters (API < 23). But simply the getParameters() for the front camera doesn't return any information of the built in front flash. For the app it just seems like there is no front flash available.
2. Then i tried to use the Camera2 API, introduced in API >= 23 and there the same Problem occurs. Fetching camera characteristics and then check if FLASH_INFO is available just results in returning false. Also trying to just activate the flash unit with setTorchMode(FRONT_CAMERA, true) throws an exception which says: No flash unit available.

I currently only have Samsung Galaxy A6 as test device with built in front flash. The same code works fine for the rear (back) camera without any problems.

ad 1)

```
try {
            Camera camera;
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);

            if (camera == null) {
                return false;
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
                camera.release();
                return false;
            }
    ...
```

It just quits at that point because .getFlashMode() returns null for the front camera. Next steps would be to check the supportedFlashModes and then call setParamater of Camera.

ad 2)

```
try {
        String camID = null;
        for(String cameraID : mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID);

        int orientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (orientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {

                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE)) {
                        camID = cameraID;
                    }
        }

        if(camID != null) {
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(camID, true);
        }

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        ...
    }
```

These are only snippets for simply activating the front flash, but both methods act like the hardware response without a built in front flash.

Answer (score 1):

After research it seems that some phone manufacturers are using private APIs to control hardware. Especially Samsung and Huawei are making use of that. The main camera app on a device is mainly controlled by that API and Frontflash can be used as expected. But even big camera apps like Instagram and Snapchat can't get rid of that and are also not able to activate e.g. Frontflash.

For own purposes the hardware just doesn't provide any features for activating Frontflash on some devices, it just reacts like there is no built-in frontflash. *For now there are no solutions available for this problem.*

Exisiting workarounds are doing a whitening of the screen to lighten up the environment in front of the phone.

Comment: There may not be straightforward solutions, but there's always a way. In an overkill scenario, you could see how samsung uses the flash (download official samsung firmware and study it) and use the API. Of course I don't yet know if the API requires some signature or root access, but there are workarounds for both cases. I don't think OP's intentios get this far, though. Your workaround is far more reasonable. Just posting this for the sake of a complete answer.